# Why does add_summary take an Integer for global_step rather than the natural TF variable global_step

Tags: tensorflow

When using the tf.summary.Filewriter we can save the global step (to organize data in Tensorboard)

```
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('directory',sess.graph)
global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)

% run some training, global_step iterated by calls to optimizer 

writer.add_summary(summary,global_step=GLOBAL_STEP)
```

Why does add_summary need an GLOBAL_STEP to be an int rather than the tf variable global_step?  Since it the argument is explicitly named global_step, it seems like it is not meant to be used in a scenario where you have some step/count that is *not* the global step.

Is this just to save having to pass a session argument to the writer?  Why would you be running the writer outside of an environment with a running session?

Comment: I think writer.add_summary(summary,global_step=GLOBAL_STEP) is called after sess.run(...) like this you can control when you want to write in Tensorboard. Sometimes it can be very slow to write in Tensorboard at every steps (mostly if you are using a lot of summaries like audios, images or embeddings).
You can do things like :
`for i in range(iterations):
  summ =   sess.run(...)
  if i % 20 == 0 : writer.add_summary(summ,global_step=i)`

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you train your models for hundreds of thousand of steps. Saving each time all the summaries is expensive and does not make that much sense.

Probably it is selected to be an integer ([it is documented that it is an integer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter#add_summary)), because mostly it is executed in this loop

```
for i in range(maximum_number_of_steps):
  # do your optimization.
  writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=i)
```

*it seems like it is not meant to be used in a scenario where you have some step/count that is not the global step*. Not really it can be any integer that you can reason about. You can have it `i // 1000` if you save to summary every 1k iterations.